# Print without starting new line

Tags: python

Im trying to reproduce this c for loop (below) in python. but the result displays each iteration on a new line is there a way to print and not start a new line?

Code in C++:

```
int pennies = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i = i + 1)//cout "o" for every penny
{
    cout << "o";
}
```

output:

```
oooooooooo
```

And in python I have tried:

```
pennies = 10
for i in range(pennies):
    print("o")
```

output:

```
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
```

Comment: print('.', end="")

Comment: alternatively, `print("o"*pennies)`.

Comment: or `''.join(['o' for _ in range(10)])`

Answer (score 0):

Specify `end` to the print command:

```
print("o", end='')
```

Comment: Had no affect on my output

Comment: You're doing something else wrong, then.  Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Try it once and see output

Comment: Yes, without the end='' it puts a space in between each o, but it at least didn't produce a new line every time, which is what he was asking for.